# Using WinRT BackgroundUploader with Windows Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-store-apps, azure-storage, winjs

In a Windows 8 app using JavaScript, I am trying to upload a file to Windows Azure Blob Storage using a Shared Access Signature defined [in this technique](http://www.nickharris.net/2012/11/how-to-upload-an-image-to-windows-azure-storage-using-mobile-services/) but I want to use the WinRT BackgroundUploader instead of the standard storage client uploader. When I call this code, nothing happens and the storage container is empty in the Windows Azure management console.

Has anyone done this before?

Does anyone have suggestion on how I should put the SAS into the BackgroundUploader's serverCredential property?

```
            table.insert(upload)
        .then(function (e) {

            var backgroundTransfer = Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer,
                uploader = new backgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader(),
                uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(upload.sas),
                operation,
                sasToken = uri.query.substr(1);

            uploader.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.contentType);
            uploader.setRequestHeader("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");

            operation = uploader.createUpload(uri, file);

            operation.startAsync().then(function (uploadComplete) {
                console.info(uploadComplete);
                complete("https://" + uri.host + "/" + upload.containerName + "/" + file.name);
            },
            function (uploadError) {
                console.error(uploadError);
            },
            function (uploadProgress) {
                console.info(uploadProgress);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please set [BackgroundUploader.Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.method.aspx) to "PUT", because the default "POST" method cannot be used to upload a blob. In addition to that, please check the following:

- SAS token should have write permission.
- The file being uploaded must be smaller than 64MB, because that is the maximum limit allowed by [Put Blob API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx).